# Dynamically calculating a throughput period

Tags: mysql, t-sql

i'm trying to find an elegant way of calculating a throughput period.
I currently have two dates:

1. 1 Nov 2017
2. 31 Jan 2018

If I have a record that falls in between these two dates it will be set to have throughput period 1.

As time progresses my records might have a date that is past 31 Jan and it needs to fall in the second period, so period 2 etc.

This continues on until the end of time(potentially) - My current setup is a linking table with about 7 sets of different throughput periods(preset). I use this table to join to in order to determine the period that the report is pulling for.

This isn't the greatest way of doing it and I dont (yet) have the ability to create code that dynamically calculates it, any ideas how SQL can be used to calculate this on the fly?

Looking to brainstorm here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have preset ranges then a case statement could work.

[image]

Comment: Hi @decompiled this is currently how I populated my linking table, thanks for the response though. I am looking for something more automated vs. me specifying the dates in the table. If there is no way we i'll continue in my ways. Thanks again!

Comment: @escGoat007 thanks for the update.  In that case you will want to take your min and max date and calculate periods based on days or months or years in the range.